# IBM memory, whats wrong, bought wrong type?

Tags: memory, ibm

I have this server

IBM System x3250 M3
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3450 @ 2.67GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.7GHz
2 GB PC3-10600 ECC DDR3 SDRAM
HDD 500 TB Hotplug
Windows server 2008

this is screenshot the default memory, micron PC3-10600R 2gb, its working well to entering windows
http://freakimage.com/images/113memory_ram_micron_PC3_.jpg

then i want to change to higher memory, i bought this memory, samsung PC3-10600R 4gb
http://freakimage.com/images/602memory_ram_samsung_mic.jpg

but its hang in uEFI boot, cant move forward to windows

already googling it, no solution yet everywhere
please take a look the screenshot, do i bought wrong new memory, if it is maybe i still can replace to the seller with another memory

Answer (score 0):

I have found that not all memory plays "nicely" well together....especially when using different vendors.  I'd suggest returning the memory and try a different vendor.

You should be sure you are installing memory in appropriate matching slots.  Each manufacturer is a bit different in how more memory should be added and where memory must be placed within the slots.  You'll have to consult the vendor documentation.

You do not say, but I assume that all the memory is ECC.  Mixing ECC and non-ECC has been problematic for me.

On some systems BIOS modifications need to be made for any memory enhancement.